# Hyperref: destination with the same identifier (...) has been already used, duplicate ignored

Tags: hyperref, warnings

From the MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir} 

\usepackage{graphicx}
\newsubfloat{figure}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \subbottom[Image A]{\includegraphics[width=0.5\columnwidth]{example-image-a}}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \subbottom[Image B]{\includegraphics[width=0.5\columnwidth]{example-image-b}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I get the warning `destination with the same identifier (name{subfigure.1}) has been already used, duplicate ignored`. If the `[h]` or the `\usepackage{hyperref}` is removed, the warning disappears.

- Why do I get this warning?
- How is it best resolved?
- And what are the implications of continuing with this warning?

(I get several of these warnings in my non-MWE document, and I still want to link to the subfigures including page numbers using `cleveref` and `varioref`.)

Comment: The numbering scheme is not clear to me, both figures are labelled with `(a)` (also without `hyperref`).

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek I removed the figure caption in order to make a MWE. If the caption is added, they will be numbered as `1(a)` and `2(a)`, respectively.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Package `hyperref` needs to be loaded *before* `\newsubfloat`. The macro calls `\@addtoreset`, which is supported and patched by `hyperref` to fix the anchor name issue. But if the macro is called before, then the original version of `\@addtoreset` is called without the patch, and the anchor names would have to be fixed manually. But this is not necessary with the right order:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newsubfloat{figure}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
  \subbottom[Image A]{\includegraphics[width=0.5\columnwidth]{example-image-a}}
  \caption{First}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
  \subbottom[Image B]{\includegraphics[width=0.5\columnwidth]{example-image-b}}
  \caption{Second}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow, that was an easy fix! Thanks. Obviously the third question in the list is redundant now.