# Cannot reproduce the following solution to the problem of \ref not working for \label inside \subbottom in 'memoir'

Tags: floats, hyperref, captions, memoir

It seems that using \label inside \subbottom causes known problems inside the 'memoir' class of documents.

Although I already solved the problem, I was stumped by the fact that I cannot reproduce one of the solutions here in TEX: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/303156/107951

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newsubfloat{figure}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
  \subbottom[Image A]{\includegraphics[width=0.5\columnwidth]{example-image-a}}
  \caption{First}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
  \subbottom[Image B]{\includegraphics[width=0.5\columnwidth]{example-image-b}}
  \caption{Second}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I copied it verbatim and compiled it, and keep getting the warning:
"pdfTex warning (ext4): destination with the same identifier (name{subfigure.1}) has been already used, duplicate ignored"

I'm using TEXnicCenter 2.02 (64 bits) and basic-miktex-2.9.5997 (64 bits).

The error occurs independently of the order of \usepackage{hyperref} and \newsubfloat{figure} (i.e., both the original question and the solution in [Hyperref: destination with the same identifier (...) has been already used, duplicate ignored](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/303155/hyperref-destination-with-the-same-identifier-has-been-already-used-dupl) lead to the same error):

[image]

[image]

Log: http://textuploader.com/53jkc

Comment: The linked example works for me out of the box. Please show us your document rather

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Do you mean include the code in the question, attach the .tex file or attach the .pdf?

Comment: Update your question by pasting the code of  *minimal* example into it. You cannot attach files.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I am literally using the code in the link, is it not a _minimal_ _working_ _example_?

Comment: Where are you placing the label? It should go in side the `[...]` option. And please update your example, there are no labels or references here, so this example cannot give you the warning you mention.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer You are right, it doesn't even have the \label, but I still get the warning (I added a picture).
So the problem is apparently not the label.

Comment: Have you tried deleting the aux files and recompiled. I get no errors or warnings with your MWE

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Yes, I just copied the .tex file to a new folder and ran it to be sure before posting the error. This is not super important, since I have a solution to the original problem I am having, but it requires me using the subcaption package, which I wanted to avoid. Don't loose sleep over it :)

Comment: @AFSRodrigues: Do you have realized that daleif was making a lot of comments, not me? ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Duh... Sorry for the spam, I really didn't notice.

Answer (score 1):

In your example code you have `\newsubfloat{figure}` *behind* `\usepackage{hyperref}`. This is correct and compile without warnings.

But in your screenshot you have `\newsubfloat{figure}` *before*  `\usepackage{hyperref}`, and this leads to the warning as now hyperref can't patch the subfloat.

Comment: Sorry, I was trying both the question and the solution to see the difference and posted the wrong one. But the warning persists. I've updated the question with both images.

Comment: Show the complete log-file of the compilation of the example with the \newsubfloat behind hyperref.

Comment: Here it is http://textuploader.com/53jkc

Comment: I can not reproduce the warning, but your system is older than mine.    It is rather curious that your memoir is from 2015 but your hobsub-generic version is older than the one in texlive 2014.

Comment: Ok, no problem. As I said in the question, I've solved the problem through other means, it was just strange that a verbatim copy of the solution in that thread kept giving the warning. Thanks for looking into it.