# Beamer presentation WITH NOTES. Warning!! "destination with the same identifier has been already used, duplicate ignored"

Tags: beamer, warnings, notes

I hope this question is not a duplicate; I have seen people observing this same warning, but in a totally different context, like [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/303155/hyperref-destination-with-the-same-identifier-has-been-already-used-dupl) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/310833/pdftex-warning-ext4-destination-with-the-same-identifier-namechoice-1-has).

The difference is I do not use hyperref for anything, but this problem shows when I attempt to have notes included in my Beamer presentation.

Notably, this warning didn't show with texlive 2013, I am experiencing it with texlive 2015, as I just upgraded to it.

The warning is the following:

> destination with the same identifier (name{Navigation2}) has been already used, duplicate ignored

And here a super simple MWE to reproduce it:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation> {
    \usepackage{pgfpages}
    \setbeameroption{show notes on second screen=right}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame with notes 1}
FIRST FRAME CONTENTS
\note{
    Notes for the first frame here
}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame with notes 2}
SECOND FRAME CONTENTS
\note{
    Notes for the second frame here
}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Has anybody observed this warning in the context of a Beamer presentation when hyperref is not used, but notes need to be shown? Does anybody know how to get rid of it? It appears once per slide, so it is really annoying to see soooo many warnings... Thanks!

Comment: You are using `hyperref`. Beamer depends on it.

Comment: Everything Beamer does is a link: your contents is linked, your references and cross-references are linked. You may have buttons. You may have form fields. You have bookmarks. You have instructions for the PDF viewer. All the clicks and interactive stuff depends on `hyperref`. Every slide of every frame has target anchors for stuff to link to. The complaint is the standard one: the names aren't unique or the destinations don't exist, so the links won't work correctly. (The standard destination mentioned is usually the first slide of the first frame.)

Comment: Oh right yes I get what you say, so does it mean it is trying to place the slide links on the little slide preview in the notes section and those links get duplicated? Is there a way to tell it to do it correctly? I never saw this warning on earlier TL versions...

Comment: I don't know, sorry. I see these warnings even without notes and saw them also in previous versions. I'd be surprised if Beamer itself is doing anything especially different, though I'm not sure about `hyperref`.

Comment: It seems I am encountering the same problems as this question from 2011 that still remains unsolved (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29219/hyperref-problems-in-beamer-when-using-notes)... I experienced before non-working navigation when placing the notes on the left, so I switched to the right in all my documents; however, the "destination..." warning only started to appear now, with TL2015

Comment: This really looks like an long standing bug in Beamer... it should at least be documented that navigation links will not work if you place the notes on the left, and that you will encounter warnings if you decide to use notes at all... has this been reported?

Comment: @DaniCee I am not sure if this is a beamer bug or rather the fault of `pgfpages`.

Answer (score 3):

**Workaround**

This will disable hyperref, so just be warned that thinks like the navigation symbols will no longer work:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation> {
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen=right}
}

\begin{document}
\NoHyper
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame with notes 1}
FIRST FRAME CONTENTS
\note{
Notes for the first frame here
}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame with notes 2}
SECOND FRAME CONTENT
\note{
Notes for the second frame here
}
\end{frame}
\endNoHyper
\end{document}
```

Comment: Well actually the navigation symbols are probably the main reason I do my presentations in Beamer...

Comment: Should this be considered a bug and reported?

Comment: Isn't this a bit drastic? Like killing the patient to ameliorate their pain!

Comment: @cfr It might be a workaround for a subgroup of people (for example I would not notice the difference, as I normally neither use the navigation symbols nor have navigation bars. Probably the only instances I need hyperref in beamer is for links to additional resources when distribution the slides to students or colleagues. But in this case, it will be a version without notes, so no problem :)

Comment: Hello, I am still struggling with this and have a presentation due in 2 weeks... has anybody come up with a solution in which I can get rid of the warnings but keep the navigation, which I need?? I really don't recall this behavior in previous versions of texlive...

Comment: @DaniCee I doubt that many people will see your comment. Maybe try with a bounty to attract attention?

Comment: I am going to start a new question later with new updates and a bounty...

Comment: please follow up in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/350993/beamer-presentation-with-notes-navigation-does-not-work-properly-and-destinati there are more problems, like table of contents links not working either...