# hyperref links to first subcaptionref with memoir

Tags: hyperref, memoir, subfloats

This is more of a bug report than a question.

When using memoir's subcaptions (not the subcaption package) and links with the hyperref package, references to subfigures always point to the first instance of that label. Here's a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\newsubfloat{figure}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \subbottom[foo\label{foo}]{\includegraphics{figure1}}
  \subbottom[bar\label{bar}]{\includegraphics{figure2}}
  \caption{\subcaptionref{foo} foo and \subcaptionref{bar} bar.}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
  \subbottom[qux\label{qux}]{\includegraphics{figure3}}
  \subbottom[baz\label{baz}]{\includegraphics{figure4}}
  \caption{\subcaptionref{qux} qux and \subcaptionref{baz} baz.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The `subcaptionref` on the second figure ((a) qux and (b) baz) will link to the sub figures with the same labels on the first figure ((a) foo and (b) bar). [Here](https://github.com/joaomlourenco/novathesis/issues/39)'s someone else on the internet with the same problem.

I've found that I can work around this by declaring the sub figures after loading the hyperref package, i.e.:

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newsubfloat{figure} % this line was moved to after \usepackage{hyperref}
```

But I would guess that this is something that should be fixed on hyperref or memoir (or documented in one of them).

Comment: Possibly [duplicate](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/303155/hyperref-destination-with-the-same-identifier-has-been-already-used-dupl)

Comment: Personally I don't think there is something to fix. Loading `hyperref` after (nearly) all other packages so it can patch them, and applying the (patched) commands afterwards is the standard way `hyperref` has to be handled. Same with `\newfloat` offered by `float` etc. See also: http://www.texfaq.org/FAQ-hyperdupdest So using `\newsubfloat` after `hyperref` is not a work-around, instead it's how it should be.